# How to animate and fade in an image once passed a certain point in a responsive page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to fade in and slide to the left an image once the image is in the viewport. I having issues getting the code to operate properly at the moment, but also thinking forwards what would need to change in order for the jQuery to work with responsive movement of div heights.

**Code Below**

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(window).one("scroll", function () {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= 700) 
            $('#iphone').fadeIn(1000).animate({
                left: '200px'
            });     
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="/images/iPhone-6.png" height="250px" width="auto" id="iphone">
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry if I'm just unfamiliar, but `$(window).one` ? I believe that's supposed to be `on`, and as far as I know there is no event called `"phone"`. What you may be looking for is `$(window).scroll(function() { //Do stuff });`

Comment: Sorry the phone was my fault didnt realise it was there. Have made the changes to reflect that. Have used .one because I only want the script to run once?

Comment: Oh, understood! Check my edited answer below - is it of any help?

Comment: https://github.com/jasonmit/landmark.js/blob/master/readme.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(window).one("phone"...` - I don't think that `"phone"` is a valid event in jQuery.

If you're trying to get an event to trigger when a page scrolls, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
<script>
      var iphonePosition = $('#iphone').offset().top;

      $(window).one("scroll", function() {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= iphonePosition) 
          $('#iphone').fadeIn(1000).animate({
            left: '200px'
        });     
      });
</script>
```

Please note that your use of `.one()` means this event will happen on the very first scroll only, regardless of what happens inside the function. If this is not desired behavior, consider just using `$(window).scroll(function() {...` and wrapping the guts of the function in another `if` like so:

```
<script>
      var iphonePosition = $('#iphone').offset().top;

      $(window).on("scroll", function() {

        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (currentScroll >= iphonePosition) {
            $('#iphone').fadeIn(1000).animate({
              left: '200px'
            });

            $(window).off(); //Our fade-in was triggered, unbind the event
        }

      });
</script>
```

Comment: Great thanks Tyler Roper, that has worked on the whole. The fade in didn't work though. Also do you know the best way to automatically adjust the 700 in this case to a variable in `(currentScroll >= 700)` so that it displays the difference from the iphone div to the top.

Comment: @JamesParsons I believe I understand what you're after. Can you check out my edit?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option
1. Add position:absolute for the id- iphone to make left:200px to show effect
2.Use .on function instead of .one, if animate to take effect on every scrollTop and not just once.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" height="250px" width="auto" id="iphone">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#iphone{
  position:absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
      $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= 100) {
                     $('#iphone').fadeIn(1000).animate({
            left: '200px'
        });  
        }
      }

);
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqYXKJ

Answer (score -1):

poll for `document.scrollTop`

if you want to check if an image is inside of the viewport.
you should get the document location of your image and subtract the scrollTop value.